# Lose "Blog Archive" from page title

Tags: posts, title

Right now the title of a post page on my blog reads like this... Blog Name >> Blog Archive >> Post Title

I don't see the need for "Blog Archive" to be in there and would like to remove it. I've looked in single.php and style.css and I'm not seeing any reference to "Blog Archive" in there that I can remove.

Any suggestions?

Much appreciated.

Eddie

Comment: Did you look in the "Archive" template file? That's most likely where it is. If it's not we're going to need more information about your theme to answer your question

Comment: Hi Eileen. I looked in both archive.php and archives.php and I couldn't find it in either. I'm using the simpleX theme by wpshoppe.com

Comment: Are you sure your theme is causing this? I took a quick look at the theme and installed it and it's not happening locally on mine. Do you have a breadcrumb plugin installed?

Comment: No breadcrumb plugin Eileen. Only Plugin I have installed and activated is Disqus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that you're talking about the browser "title" at the top; that wasn't clear from your original post

Go into your `header.php` and at the top look for this line

`<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> &raquo; Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> </title>`

and remove

`<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> &raquo; Blog Archive <?php } ?>`

Comment: Glad I could help. Since this answered the question can you please mark the answer as "accepted" so the question shows up as answered for others who also have the same question? Thanks!

Comment: I would remove all but `<?php wp_title(); ?>`. Your current markup does not play well with others.